# How to parallel process a large file without load all in memory

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a large json line file (each line is a json object). I would like to read each line and process each line in parallel. 
Here is what I got:

```
import gzip
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd
from json import loads

def process_file(file_line):
    json_line = loads(file_line)
    data = json_line.get('data', None)
    if data:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        return df.groupby(['style']).score.describe()
    return pd.DataFrame()

pool = mp.Pool(8)
jobs = []
with gzip.open('2018.jl.gz') as f:
    for line in f:
        jobs.append(pool.apply_async(process_file,(f)))

for job in jobs:
    job.get()

pool.close()
```

However, the processing takes longer than reading the file and it end up with appending too many jobs and causing memory issues.
Is there a way I could parallel this? How could I coded it the way that each thread will grab a line and process the line and when it finish, it will grab a new line, and the loop would pause if all threads are busy?

Comment: You want to create a DataFrame per line?

Comment: Maybe you just need this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html ? It can read gzip as well other compressions.

Comment: @khachik yes. each line turn into a data frame and do some processing to it.

Comment: And, finally, if you really want to implement what you describe, you can apply `pool.imap(process_file, f)`.

Comment: @khachik the point is not read all things in memory. I need to process it line by line and do some aggregations. and I would like to do this in parallel.

Comment: pandas won't read the whole file into memory if you don't tell it to do so (check the decriptions of `lines` and `chunksize` arguments in the above link).

Comment: @khachik the return of read_json would be the entire file right? The file is too large if I don't do some aggregation.

Comment: You are most likely creating the jobs faster than they are processed. This results in many unstarted jobs being in memory. You should add a mechanism to create jobs in batches or via a length limited queue. You might have to read in a seperate thread for that.

Comment: @KlausD. a length limited queue sounds like a promising solution. I thought about it but I don't know how to pause reading the file and wait for thread to finish. Do you have an example or something I could take a look? Thanks.

Comment: For example: `queue = Queue(10)`, then in the reader thread `queue.put(line, block=True)`

Comment: `pool.imap(process_file, f)` does what you asked in your post - each process will process a line until `f` is exhausted. The overall performance will depend on the number of processes you create the `Pool` object with. And no, pandas won't read the entire file into memory, if used properly.